# Add series of category through parameter in Line chart?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a Line chart where i have four series of categories like :-

Revenue, 
Target, Cost and Gross Margin.

And chart will have all four categories by default.

Now I want to pass these categories through parameter(check-box) where user can select which category he wants to see in chart because sometime he just want to see revenue trend and not interested in target trend over the months for a year.
Default value for the input control will be Revenue and if he wants to see target he can add a category series for Target by selecting Target check-box parameter.

Something like this :-

[image]

Is it doable in iReport?

My category series code :- in this category series i have created a dumy series with 0 value.

```
<categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{p_target}) ? "Target" :"Target"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{p_target}) ? $F{MTHYR} :""]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{p_target}) ? $F{TARGET} : $F{dumy}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{p_revenue}) ? "Revenue" :"Revenue"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{p_revenue}) ? $F{MTHYR} :""]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{p_revenue}) ?$F{REVENUE}  : $F{dumy}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{p_cost}) ? "Cost" :"Cost"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{p_cost}) ? $F{MTHYR} :""]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{p_cost}) ? $F{COST} : $F{dumy}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{p_gross_margin}) ? "Gross Margin" :"Gross Margin"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{p_gross_margin}) ? $F{MTHYR} :$F{MTHYR}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{p_gross_margin}) ? $F{GROSS_MARGIN} : $F{dumy}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
```

After solution suggested by @MisterMichaelK i changed the dummy series default value to -50 but now my problem is with Category Expression which is also a required filed,If statement is like this : new Boolean($P{p_revenue}) ? $F{MTHYR} :"" , but it shows always something for every series like in above image:-
[image]

Comment: And what about *Java* code? Is it acceptable solution?

Comment: @Alex Whatever can be done through iReport only.I do not have much knowledge about java.

Comment: Why dont you use Multi Select Input Control for those categories and select the required from there itself? I had a similar situation where user wanted to select 2 different categories and I achieved the same through Multi Select Query

Answer (score 0):

First, in your iReport chart, create boolean (true/false) parameters for each checkbox input.

Next, right click on your chart and select "Chart Data". Click "Details". Select your series, click "Modify". In the "Value Expression" box, create an if statement similar to this:

$P{TargetBox} == true ? $F{YourSeries} : -1

where $P{TargetBox} is the name of the parameter you created and $F{YourSeries} is whatever expression you use for that series. -1 can be as big a negative value as you need to make your line disappear under the chart's 0-line.

Make sure to set your chart's Range Axis Min Value (in chart properties) to 0 so it doesn't show anything under the 0-line when it renders.

Repeat this for each check box you make. This should make the series only show when the corresponding box is checked.

Comment: This i have already tested, as i know in the Value expression, we can not have null value condition.

Comment: You could set up a blank dummy series to put in the other part of the IF statement.

Comment: Even we add dummy series which already i am doing but in my case dummy series is not blank as i have already told you we can not have null values in Value expression and blank dummy means null values.

Comment: Sorry, I meant you can just use zero values. If statement like this: $P{TargetBox} == true ? $F{YourSeries} : -1 This will give you a line along the bottom of your chart at a value of -1 for the "dummy series". You can then set your Range Axis Min Value (under chart properties) to 0 so that anything under 0 isn't displayed. If your lines are so thick that they still show, you can change -1 to -50 or some big negative value so it's buried under the chart's minimum.

(edited original answer to reflect this)

Comment: Thanks but what about the Category Expression which is also a required filed,If statement is like this : new Boolean($P{p_revenue}) ? $F{MTHYR} :"" , but it shows always something for every series like in above image. I have added a new image.

Comment: To get rid of the unused series in the legend I think you would need to build a chart customizer.